# Override ccsprite draw function cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, sprite

I have been through all the custom draw questions related to cocos2d-x on stack overflow and other places, I would just like to know if it's possible to override the draw function in CCSprite, not in CCLayer. I want to draw a rounded rectangle. I am used to controlling what is being drawn on screen using spriteBatches in libgdx and XNA (R.I.P :( ). I am a bit lost as to how i can do custom draw for my sprite objects. Below is what I have and it does not work.

```
// object.h
  private:
    std::string _colourLabel;

    int width;
    int height;

    cocos2d::Vec2 position;
public:
    PLOPPP(std::string colour, cocos2d::Vec2 pos, int width, int height);

    virtual void draw(cocos2d::Renderer *renderer, const cocos2d::kmMat4 &transform, bool transformUpdated);
    void onDraw(const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags);

//object.cpp
void PLOPPP::draw(cocos2d::Renderer* renderer, const cocos2d::kmMat4& transform, bool transformUpdated)
{
    cocos2d::ccDrawColor4F(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cocos2d::ccDrawLine(ccp(0, 0), ccp(100, 100));
}

void PLOPPP::onDraw(const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{
    cocos2d::ccDrawColor4F(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cocos2d::ccDrawLine(ccp(0, 0), ccp(100, 100));
}
```

I have also put break points in both the methods and it's never called. I also tried to use the sprite->visit() method to direct the render component into the onDraw method as recommended on other questions. Cocos's has a horrible documentation so I use their test projects and read the header files. I see that there is a draw method to override but it's not hitting. I am not very experienced in C++ but I have a good grip on Programming concepts and writing games in general. So you can use any terms you would use to explain to other programmers.

The reason why I want to use CCsprite is to get the benefits of the actions. I also tried to use the CCNode class as a base but it still does not hit. I don't want to make every object a layer because that would go completely against the concept of having objects in a game drawn on a layer. If anyone can suggest any way I can draw custom shapes as sprites, that is also affected by the actions applied to it. It would be greatly appreciated.

If you think I could benefit from other posts please point to it. This should not be a difficult process but it seems to be taking up a lot of my time. If I could just draw a line I'll be able to fly through the rest of the challenges. I just want to draw a custom something.

Comment: what version of Cocos2d-x is this? I think the `onDraw` is now deprecated in newer versions. your `draw()` looks current though.

Comment: It's the latest. V3.2. I resorted to using images and scaling them to get the rounded rectangles. It was taking up too much of the dev time just trying to do a custom call. I will need it in future games so any help would still be useful. I just want to draw one line, but i;ve tried everything and the method never hits. @GameDeveloper I must be doing something wrong somewhere, and I know it's hard to track when you don't have the actual code.